# eps to pdf by Texmaker in different sizes

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps

I'm having a problem with the automatic conversion from EPS to PDF. I'm creating `.eps` graphs from matlab and want to include them in a `.tex` file. With the help of Texmaker these EPS files get converted to PDF to be shown in my document. This is only one example, I noticed there is not any pattern to it: some are good; others aren't.

I've noticed different sizes for similar graphs:
[image]

The figure on the left bottom is the figure I want. It is like this figure is zoomed in, which gives a better results. The other three are just in their normal format but these are not readible in my document.

I'm using Texmaker on a W10 computer with a template I received from school.

Code for my figures looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[left=2.15cm,top=1.5cm,right=2.15cm,bottom=1.5cm,nohead]{geometry}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/4eabsOD.eps}
    \caption{Assembly with shell \& lock}
    \label{step1fig1}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/4eabsID.eps}
    \caption{Principle pneumatic fitting}
    \label{figpneum2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/4erelOD.eps}
    \caption{Assembly with shell \& lock}
    \label{step1fig1}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/4erelID.eps}
    \caption{Principle pneumatic fitting}
    \label{figpneum2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does any one know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome! I've tidied up your code and question a bit, but could you complete it so that it can be compiled? To format code, highlight it and click the `{}` button or use ctrl+k. This will indent it by 4 spaces. Don't use the extension when naming the graphic file for inclusion i.e. don't include the `.eps`. Could you say what is different about the bottom left graph compared with the others? I don't really understand what you want to change.

Comment: Seems like the error was not caused by eps to pdf conversion, like I thaught. The problem was due to the creation of the graphs, I forgot renaming some settings so they didn't applied on all the graphs. :) Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by some incorrect settings in Matlab which the OP has now corrected.